# Selecting similar options from two different div-class dropdowns using Selenium WebDriver (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, webforms, selenium-chromedriver

Im working on a project that involves submitting an online form. Currently I have no issues logging into the website, and accessing the form, however, there are two drop down menus in the form which my code conditionally struggles to fill out. One is asking for the state of a home address, and the second is asking for the drivers license issue state. Both of these drop downs have the same list of selectable options (My suspicion on the source of the problem). So with this being said, my main issue was that when I try to fill out both of these drop downs, the first one successfully fills out with no issue, however, the second one will only fill out if the selected value is different than the first. Just to reiterate, these are NOT  class drop downs, so Selenium's select functions will not work. These are the two drop down menus in question:
[image: Image of HTML Element of the second drop down when California is selected]
[image: The two interactive drop down menus]

The following two lines of code are what I have currently been trying to fill out California for both the first and second dropdown values:

### First Dropdown (Works Perfectly)

```
drp1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[7]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
drp1a = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text() ='California']"))).click()
```

### Second Dropdown

Does not struggle to open the drop down list itself, however, cannot select value if it is equal to first dropdowns value

```
drp2 = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/main/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[9]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div"))).click()
time.sleep(3)
drp2a = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[text() ='California']"))).click()
```

I have been searching for an answer but nothing has worked so far. If someone could please help me in seeing where this issue lies, that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If two elements have the same locators you can use indexes to tell selenium with which one of them you want to work.
For the second dropdown's option you can use `(By.XPATH, "(//*[text() ='California'])[2]")`

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! Now after implementing that code into mine, I have interestingly received a new error, "ElementClickInterceptedException:" and from reading the error it is looking like the next div element would "receive the click". Would you happen to have an idea of what is going on here?

Comment: To be able to understand which element intercepted the click I need to see the error in its entirety, as well as the source code of the page or at least the elements you are working with.

Comment: Error Message: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <span id="10d86803e6bd9ad402099f238983c41b_selectedChoice" class="DropdownWidget---accessibilityhidden">...</span> is not clickable at point (154, 323). Other element would receive the click: <div class="ColumnLayout---column ColumnLayout---column_padding_standard ColumnLayout---align_start ColumnLayout---top ColumnLayout---width_narrow_plus ColumnLayout---stack_when_phone ColumnLayout---overflow" data-padding-left="0" data-padding-right="-20" data-divider="false" data-stacked="false">...</div>

Comment: How would you like me to send the source code?

Comment: You can use some screenshot tool, make a couple of screenshots, upload them into screenshot service's cloud. And then post the links here in the comments.

Comment: Let me know if this works, the highlighted section is the second dropdown in the question: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEx9a.png

Comment: As far as I can see, it says that the next element (according to attributes, it's somehow related to phone number) covers the item you are trying to click. Can you look what happens on UI at the time when the error appears? It would be great if you can screenshot that.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFCbj.png , Basically what happens is the first location fills out "California" and then the second drop down opens, but none of the states are selected. This is what the UI looks like when the error occurs.

Comment: Are sleeps still in the code? If no, put them back.<br/> Is it possible to ensure there are only two elements on the page with xpath `//*[text() ='California']`? You can check it using find (opens with CTRL+f) in the elements. [Example](https://i.imgur.com/Dvooaxh.png)